# How to make a matrix from multiple datasets with inconsistent values in each dataset?

Tags: r, matrix, data-wrangling

I am working with multiple datasets, and am trying to combine them into a matrix, where the each column is a gene name, and the table values are the gene expression data.

The problem is that some of the datasets are missing some genes or have different genes, so I do not have a complete "reference" set of genes.

```
Dataset 1                   Dataset 2
Gene     expression         Gene     expression
a        0.3                a        0.1
b        0.1                c        -0.3
e        0.2                d        0.05
f        0.2                f        -0.1


Ideal Output:

     a     b     c     d     e     f
1    0.3   0.1   NA    NA    0.2   0.2
2    0.1   NA    -0.3  0.05  NA    -0.1
```

I was trying to first make a loop that would create the gene columns from the first data frame, and then only add columns if they were not only present in the data frame. From there I was going to make an if-else statement to add the expression data, and NA if not.

I "think" this code works, but the trouble is that it is very slow (currently running still with only a small subset of datasets) because there are 20,000 genes per dataset, and I will eventually be using 100s of datasets.

How can I make a a column for every gene present in any dataset without overlap in a more efficient way?

```
copynumber_files <- list.files(data_dir)

copynumbers <- data.frame()

for (copynumber_file in copynumber_files){
  copynumber_df <- read.csv(copynumber_file, sep="\t")
  for (i in 1:nrow(copynumber_df)){
    if (!copynumber_df$gene[i] %in% copynumbers){
      copynumbers[copynumber_df$gene[i]] <- list(character(0))
    }
    else {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and family, you could do the following:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- tribble(
    ~Gene, ~expression,
    "a", 0.3, 
    "b", 0.1,
    "e", 0.2, 
    "f", 0.2
)

df2 <- tribble(
    ~Gene, ~expression,
    "a", 0.1,
    "c", -0.3,
    "d", 0.05,
    "f", -0.1
)

df <- bind_rows(
    lapply(seq_along(dflist), function(x) mutate(dflist[[x]], dataset = x))
) %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols = "dataset", names_from = Gene, values_from = expression)
```

The `lapply` function creates a variable in each dataframe called `dataset`. Since `bind_rows` can take a list of data frames, the list returned by `lapply` is bound into a single data frame where the number of rows equals the total number of rows in all of the datasets.

The `pivot_longer` function rotates the dataset from long to wide, where each gene gets its own column, each dataset its own row, and the cell values equal the expression (with `NA` where not present).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to execute this on my own data set, but I recieve this error:  ```Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"``` . I made a list of all of the DFs using the below. Any idea what is going wrong?  ```for (i in copynumber_files){
  dataframe_list <- append(dflist, read.csv(i, sep="\t"))
}```

Comment: Try adding `library(dplyr)` and `library(tidyr)` at the top of the code (I edited the answer to include it). Also you should probably be able to a list with lapply without needing a loop: `lapply(copynumber_files, read.csv, sep=“\t”`.